# Redirect to site hosted on apache server on linux not displayed after installing ssl certficate

Tags: apache, ssl, https

I installed apache2 on ubuntu 18.04 and created a simple website that can be reached (after I did port forwarding for port 80) with  `http://IP_NUMBER` .

Next, I wanted to get it working with https, and therefore followed the instructions in the link below:

https://hostadvice.com/how-to/configure-apache-with-tls-ssl-certificate-on-ubuntu-18/

This includes i.a. creating a self-signed key and certificate pair with the following command:
 `sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/ssl/private/apache-selfsigned.key -out /etc/ssl/certs/apache-selfsigned.crt`

I also did port forwarding for port 443.

It now works with both  `http://IP_NUMBER`  and  `https://IP_NUMBER`

HOWEVER, I have a domain-address (such as address.se) at one.com that I have **redirected** to  `http://IP_NUMBER` . Opening this ip-adress with  `http://www.address.se`  no longer works.

I just get the text: “Firefox Can’t Open This Page. To protect your security, 85.229.115.65 will not allow Firefox to display the page if another site has embedded it. To see this page, you need to open it in a new window. Learn more…”

Clicking “Learn more” opens this page:
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/xframe-neterror-page?as=u&utm_source=inproduct

The site contains i.a. the following text:

“If you see this error, it is usually caused by a misconfigured website that is trying to display another website without the consent of its owner. To visit a site that has shown this message, you can open the link in a New Tab or New Window in Firefox. Note that in some cases, the embedding page will not work correctly without access to the blocked page. In this case you will need to contact the owner of the broken site for troubleshooting.”

I have searched internet and Stackoverflow but can’t figure out what is wrong, so help would be great.